# Code Prediction

Tags: javascript, html, css

What can users expect to see with the following code?  Will the messages display as random or all at once?

```
      <!doctype html>
      <head>
      <title> Mathematics Review For Beginners</title>
      <script type = 'text/javascript'>
      var someValue;
      someValue= 1+1=2
      someValue= 1+2=3
      someValue= 1+3=4
      someValue= 1+4=5
      someValue= 1+5=6
      alert someValue;
      </script>
      </head>
      </html>
```

Happy Saturday!

Comment: If only there was some way to execute code and find out...

Comment: That isn't valid JavaScript. At all.

Comment: Try to run that in the browser, use the developer tools to see what you get at the 'console' tab.

Comment: No messages will display because that code is total gibberish.

Comment: David, Andrew, Paul, and Boann.  lol.

Comment: This is the message I'm getting when I run it in HTML5 validator:

The document is valid HTML5 + ARIA + SVG 1.1 + MathML 2.0 (subject to the utter previewness of this service).?
I'll run in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing, `1+1=2` will return an assignment error, `alert someValue` will return an identifier error.

Comment: If I wanted the browser to display all the values at once, what changes do you recommend?  I've got errors to work out.

Comment: The JavaScript you'll need:
`for(var values = [], counter = 1; counter < 6; counter++)
  values.push(eval("1 + " + counter);
alert(values);`

Comment: Thanks..................